# Working with a large db (sqlite / mariadb) in PowerBi

Tags: sqlite, powerbi, mariadb, powerquery

I have a SQlite db-file of 30 GB.  This is to large to import into PowerBi Desktop (I don't have a premium-licence), so I want to use DirectQuery.
This doensn't work with SQLite (see link below).

[https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources][1]

I think it might be possible to use MariaDB (= opensource).  I never used this database and it isn't clear to me if the database needs to be installed or that it uses a single database file like sqlite (file.db) that can easily be moved around.

Any advice?  On PowerBi or the database?

Comment: Mariadb does require installing and running a service, not like SQLite

Comment: It is best practices to use views. Why would you want to import an entire database?